# Print First Letter of Each Word in a Sentence

Tags: c#

I need a simple solution for the problem in C#

Input : Any Body Can Dance

Output : ABCD

Comment: Another `could you make my work plesase` question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string inputString = "Another One Bites The Dust And Another One Down";
string[] split = inputString.Split();
foreach (string s in split)
{
    Console.Write(s.Substring(0,1));
}
```

Comment: put like this
string[] split = inputString.split(); 
Dont use below mentioned
string split[] = inputString.split();

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
string s = new string("Any Body Can Dance"
                     .Split(' ')
                     .Select(x => x.First())
                     .ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: `.Select(d => d.First)).ToArray()`. If you take s the compiler will throw an error because s is already defined. 
+1 for using the almighty LINQ